# Web Host Manager - Lock admin out of cPanels or encrypt them

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have a Reseller web server with WHM. I mostly use it for hosting websites for clients, but have set up a small cPanel account for a friend who is learning computer science in college.

It occurred to me that he might not be comfortable if he knew that I can access his cPanel account - including any email accounts he sets up - with one click from WHM, bypassing his username and password by not needing them.

I'm wondering if there's some way that I can restrict my access to his account, so that I can only log in with the password, or do a reset on it - this way at least he'd know if I accessed his account if his password wasn't working any longer, I wouldn't do this, nor would he expect me to, but it's the principle of this unrestricted access that I'm concerned about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No thats not possible, as per WHM/Cpanel design the admin who create the account does has access to that account to reset things when your friend or customer does not remember his password or account details.
Admin will have access to his client Cpanel details.